# Neo4j Cypher WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to execute several queries at the same time on the browser console, here are my requests :

```
CREATE (newNode1:NEW_NODE)
CREATE (newNode2:NEW_NODE)
MATCH (n1:LABEL_1 {id: "node1"}) CREATE (newNode1)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n1)
MATCH (n2:LABEL_2 {id: "node2"}) CREATE (newNode2)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n2)
```

When I execute them one by one there is no problem, but when I execute them at the same time, I get the following error :
    WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH

Is there any way to correct this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Add a couple of WITHs?

```
CREATE (newNode1:NEW_NODE)
CREATE (newNode2:NEW_NODE)
WITH newNode1, newNode2
MATCH (n1:LABEL_1 {id: "node1"}) 
CREATE (newNode1)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n1)
WITH newNode1, newNode2
MATCH (n2:LABEL_2 {id: "node2"}) 
CREATE (newNode2)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n2)
```

Alternatively, you could do it in a different order and avoid the WITHs, the difference being that it won't create anything if n1/n2 don't MATCH.

```
MATCH (n1:LABEL_1 { id: "node1" }) 
MATCH (n2:LABEL_2 { id: "node2" }) 
CREATE (newNode1:NEW_NODE)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n1) 
CREATE (newNode2:NEW_NODE)-[:LINKED_TO]->(n2)
```

Comment: Finally, I used the samed method as you pointed.
I wrote all my matches before my creates.

I thought there was something to separate two queries but didn't find.
Thank you!