# SyntaxError: WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm very beginner to Cypher query. So, I'm trying to understand MATCH and CREATE. Here's what I am currently defining relationship between author and the book:

```
MATCH (book1:Book1 {title: 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas'})
MATCH (author1:Author1 {name: 'Ursula K. Le Guin'})
CREATE (author1) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book1)

MATCH (book2:Book2 {title: 'A Fire Upon the Deep'})
MATCH (author2:Author2 {name: 'Vernor Vinge'})
CREATE (author2) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book2)
```

But this throws me error:

> SyntaxError: WITH is required between CREATE and MATCH

I have looked in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297679/neo4j-cypher-with-is-required-between-create-and-match) but still not able to solve this issue.

Here's what I have tried and still getting the same error:

```
MATCH (author1:Author1 {name: 'Ursula K. Le Guin'})
MATCH (book1:Book1 {title: 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas'})
WITH author1, book1
CREATE (author1) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book1)

MATCH (author2:Author2 {name: 'Vernor Vinge'})
MATCH (book2:Book2 {title: 'A Fire Upon the Deep'})
WITH author2, book2
CREATE (author2) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the syntax error is `WITH` required between `CREATE` and `MATCH`.

**`WITH` should be between `CREATE` of the third line and `MATCH` of the fifth(fourth?) line.**

WITH is needed to chain, pipe the results from one query part to next. If this is confusing you, don't worry. You can read more [here](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/with/).

As you are not passing any results from the first part to second you don't need it, but it's syntactically incorrect.

You can add WITH in your query as shown below to remove the error.

```
MATCH (book1:Book1 {title: 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas'})
MATCH (author1:Author1 {name: 'Ursula K. Le Guin'})
CREATE (author1) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book1)
WITH true as pass
MATCH (book2:Book2 {title: 'A Fire Upon the Deep'})
MATCH (author2:Author2 {name: 'Vernor Vinge'})
CREATE (author2) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book2)
```

**Alternatively, you could do it in a different order and avoid the WITHs, the difference being that it won't create anything if any of these books/authors doesn't MATCH.**

```
MATCH (author1:Author1 {name: 'Ursula K. Le Guin'})
MATCH (book1:Book1 {title: 'The Ones Who Walk Away From Omelas'})
MATCH (author2:Author2 {name: 'Vernor Vinge'})
MATCH (book2:Book2 {title: 'A Fire Upon the Deep'})
CREATE (author1) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book1)
CREATE (author2) - [:IS_AUTHOR_OF] -> (book2)
```

***P.S.: It looks like you used Book1 and Book2 instead of just Book, and same for the authors.***

Comment: Yes, it's confusing to me. But after I tried this, got `(no changes, no records)`. Obviously, this removes the error but still no relationships defined.

Comment: This should work, confirm once if you have these book and author nodes in your database. It works for me if I try after creating these nodes.

Comment: I have that. But relationship is not being defined.

Comment: I think you used Book1and Book2 instead of just Book and so for Author. Check once again

Comment: I had created like for eg.: `CREATE (author2:Author
  {
    name: 'Vernor Vinge',
    location: 'Canada',
    gender: 'Male'
  }
)`

Comment: Ah, got it now. I have to match (author2: Author). Thanks.

Comment: Right. You create a node with label 'Author' But when you are matching in your query you matching for label 'Author1' in the first part of the query and 'Author2' in the second part of the query.

Comment: Yes. Of-course! I was confused with the linked question.

Comment: BTW, I am not clear with the concept. Maybe I will understand later. Thanks anyways.